# Can't center my layout with divs

Tags: css, layout, html

I can't find a way to center my layout, keeping the video div intact. Whenever i do center it using the auto left and right margins, the div goes all over the place when i resize the window.

Is there a way around this?

http://silentcellmusic.com/test2.html

Comment: Please include the code that is relevant. Details on what you've tried. Also when I checked the link I see you really need to learn some basic html/css. E.G. inline styles go inside a `style=''` attribute. and `<style/>` elements mostly belong in the `<head>` elements not inside the `<div>`.

Comment: Stating the obvious, yes i know i need to learn. I'm new to this.

Comment: Either way..

I just want to position the main image for the layout in the center of the page, in a way that the divs don't move around when the window gets resized. I'm trying to position it around, but nothing seems to have any effect. I'm probably placing stuff inside the wrong areas.

Comment: this is almost the same question as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11785227/cant-get-my-div-to-stay-fixed-with-layout/11785393#11785393 My answer has the instructions on how to center images/divs

Comment: @user1572481 http://www.htmldog.com/guides/cssbeginner/

Answer (score 0):

For starters, there's no need to declare two seperate CSS `<style>` tags. Compile them into one or even better, call your css from an external file. Next, there's a `<div id="wrap">` in the `<head></head>` section with no closing tag. Keep your content in the body and make sure to close them up.

As for your layout itself, this should be fairly straightforward coding considering you're using a single image for the entire page. Position your image as desired and then position your video div in place with just your `top:` and `left` tags. There's no need to declare your margins, honestly. You're using absolute positioning.

Also, you should declare your `main` wrapper first for the sake of cleanliness. There's several more ways to do a site using your method (and much cleaner ones mind you), but start with this and work through it. If you need more information (for external stylesheets or the like), you can ask here, but Google is your friend.